# How to extract and convert first 6 digits of a 10 character-number into as.Date?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, date, dplyr

Let's say I have 10 digits representing a social security numbers (obviously fake in this example) stored `as.character()`.

```
df <- data.frame(number = as.character(c("1208891384", "2105650124", "0102018213")))

> df
      number
1 1208891384
2 2105650124
3 0102018213
```

The social security number represents `ddmmyy-xxxx`. I want to extract these `ddmmyy` from the character string an create a new covariate including the 6 digits `as.Date()`.

I would prefer a solution in `dplyr`

Expected output

```
> df
      number          date
1 1208891384    1989-08-12
2 2105650124    1965-05-21
3 0102018213    2001-02-01
```

And

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variable:
 $ number: chr  "1208891384" "2105650124" "0102018213"
 $ date      : Date, format: 1989-08-12 1965-05-21 ...
```

**Update**

Tried approach below on my data. Then received an error.

```
pp <- structure(list(cpr = c("0311611951", "1902521268", "1209470762"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

And

```
pp %>% mutate(b_day=substr(cpr,1,2),
       month=substr(cpr,3,4),
       year=as.numeric(substr(cpr,5,6)),
       date=as.Date(substr(cpr,1,6),'%d%m%y'),
       yearcheck=as.numeric(format(date,'%Y')),
       year2=ifelse(yearcheck>format(Sys.Date(),'%Y'),yearcheck-100,yearcheck),
       Date=as.Date(paste0(as.character(year2),month,day),'%Y%m%d'))
```

Gives

> Problem with `mutate()` input `Date`. x cannot coerce type 'closure'
> to vector of type 'character' ℹ Input `Date` is
> `as.Date(paste0(as.character(year2), month, day), "%Y%m%d")`. Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Pay attention of years, as some dates before 1970 in `R` can not be transformed properly. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(number = as.character(c("1208891384", "2105650124", "0102018213")))
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(day=substr(number,1,2),
              month=substr(number,3,4),
              year=as.numeric(substr(number,5,6)),
              date=as.Date(substr(number,1,6),'%d%m%y'),
              yearcheck=as.numeric(format(date,'%Y')),
              year2=ifelse(yearcheck>as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),'%Y')),yearcheck-100,yearcheck),
              Date=as.Date(paste0(as.character(year2),month,day),'%Y%m%d')) %>%
  select(c(number,Date))
```

Output:

```
      number       Date
1 1208891384 1989-08-12
2 2105650124 1965-05-21
3 0102018213 2001-02-01
```

Comment: Thank you @Duck. Unfortunately, I receive an error when applying to my data. See Updated post, thank you.

Comment: @cmirian I have seen it, very strange! Could you please tell me the structure of your data using `str()`?

Comment: @cmirian Also, I updated my solution, maybe there is some issue with the comparison. Please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: @cmirian Great! And sorry for forgeting that piece in the code. It is a pretty nice question and challenging +1